# Black screen on GoBack

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing an windows 8 application using "mvvm light".
But I have an issue with the GoBack of page.
It occurs not all time but +- each 5 GoBack.
I first thought that was because my page isn't completly loaded (but it wasn't a way to find the solution).
So I'm completly lost. Could someone help ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found !
For an obscure raison the GoBack worked but sometimes it automatically recall my before page.
To solve that I initialized the value that cause the call to the next page.